# If I delete a question that I have earned reputation from, do I lose it?

Tags: support

I was thinking of deleting one of my questions. It has one voteup and I would like to delete but I don't know if I still keep the reputation I earned. I don't want to try it because im not sure what will happen. But will I lose my reputation?

Answers are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll first let you know to keep in mind that you can undelete (your own) questions freely.

As for your main question, there is a set of criteria for keeping reputation on a deleted question (or answer), which can also be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222):

- The post must be at least 60 days old.
- You must have earned a net score of +3 or higher to keep the reputation.

So, if you have only one upvote on a question, you would lose that reputation.

To be frank, though, a single +5 isn't worth worrying over if you think the question isn't a good one to keep around. On the other hand, if you simply already know the answer, you could post an answer yourself. (See: [When to delete your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29850))

Comment: Dammit, you ninja'ed it.

Comment: @Mysticial FGITW!